# Authentication failed after upgrade to version 2.11.0 for windows

Tags: git

I am using Git repository in TFS 2013. After upgrading git to version 2.11.0 I am getting an authentication error on pull,clone, push etc, Git even does not ask for credentials. Downgrade to older version helps. I've also tried 2.11.0 version on 3 different machines and get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've the same issue with few machines - Windows 2008 R2/VS 2013  (TFS 2013 server)

Here is the solution:

1. Downgrade to older version ( for example 2.10.0 ).
2. Perform some git operations like pull,clone, push 
   Git will pop the credential window with user and password 
   ( type your credential user, password)
3. Upgrade to Git 2.11.0 version

Answer (score 0):

in additional :

There is a new version of GIT client 2.11.0.3

you can download GIT 2.11.0.3 from the following link : https://git-scm.com/download/win

The latest GIT 2.11.0.3 version finaly solves the authentication issue.